# How to restrict errors coming from iframe - htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, iframe

I have a php site .Im using iframe to load some contents from other site.A bulk list of errors showing in my console.Is it possible to restrict this errors in htaccess or using jquery?

Comment: Can you include any links/code and the errors from your console? We cannot be sure from your question what the problem is about.

Comment: There is nothing you can do with content or script in cross domain iframe...unless you control the code in the iframe source. It is restricted by *"same origin policy"*

Comment: @EdmundDantes Error appears in console is  402 Payment Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot suppress errors in frames from other sites. It is for security reasons.

What you can do is catch the errors - and then do some action if an error occurs. Or I would recommend to contact the site which you are including as a frame. They are the ones who can fix the errors.